# Stop Checkbox to be selected when form loads

Tags: html, checkbox

I have a simple form that has a checkbox.  THe checkbox always appears checked when the page loads.  How do I make it appear without a check when the page loads?

Here is my code:

```
                <div id="quote_inputCH" style="width: 110px">
                <div id="input_wrap">
                    <input id="checkpoints" class="styled" type="checkbox"></div>
                <label for="checkpoints">
                <div id="checkboxTITLE">
                    Checkpoints</div>
                </label></div>
```

Comment: Check the CSS and make sure it's not setting it to checked.

Comment: This html code is not checking the checkbox, there should be some javascript code that doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type to an asp:checkbox or add runat=server.  Then, in your code behind,  check to see whether or not it is the first page load (ie not a postback) and set checked = false.

Answer (score 0):

A script is checking your checkbox. What scripts are running on that page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox (not sure about the other browsers). FF will remember field that are filled (including checkboxes) even if you only do a refresh. You must do a hard refresh (shift-F5) to clear the checkbox.